# Triggers and stored procedures in web applications

Tags: web-applications, stored-procedures, triggers, lamp

I've heard that using triggers and stored procedures in web applications is considered a bad practice, especially when it comes to work with a LAMP stack. Is that true? What are the reasons? Can anyone explain it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL added stored procedure support in the recent 5.0 release. However, stored procedures have been features in closed-source relational db, such as Oracle, since the early 1990s. As a result, application featured with stored procedure generally incorporate. [1](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9652)

It has been discussed very clearly pros and cons using stored procedures to work with LAMP stack. [1](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9652)

Comment: Thansk for an answer, but... Isn't this article a little outdated? It worships stored procedures instead of objectively name pros and cons of procedures and triggers. Don't get me wrong, it names a lot of pros, but I don't belive that there are so little cons of using them. Otherwise they would be a standard tool in every webdeveloper toolbox, which they are, as far as I know,  not.